# How to prepare data for association rules in python-weka-wrapper?

Tags: python, machine-learning, weka

I'm trying to learn rules on a given data using weka in python.
Weka gets errors of 'Cannot handle string & numeric attributes'

I'm using 
https://github.com/fracpete/python-weka-wrapper3

At first, I did:

```py
loader = Loader(classname="weka.core.converters.CSVLoader")
    data = loader.load_file(path)
    data.class_is_last()
```

But got:

```py
javabridge.jutil.JavaException: weka.associations.Apriori: Cannot handle numeric attributes!
```

When trying to learn the rules.

I understand the error, weka wants nominal attributes. OK! 
I've searched and found ways to do it: 
http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/NominalToString.html

So I've tried:

```py
loader = Loader(classname="weka.core.converters.CSVLoader")
    data = loader.load_file(path)
    nominal = Filter(classname="weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.NumericToNominal", options=["-R", "first-last"])
    nominal.inputformat(data)
    nominal_data = nominal.filter(data)
    nominal_data.class_is_last()

    return nominal_data
```

But got:

```py
javabridge.jutil.JavaException: weka.associations.Apriori: Cannot handle string attributes!
```

What am I missing? 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Weka there are both `String` and `nominal` types of data. The `String` data type is a textual type with unspecified number of values (e.g. tracking Id: R99432239US) while the `Nominal` type correspond to values from a closed set (e.g. state {walking, running, sitting}).

When parsing a `csv` file, the loader assigns the data type of the attribute according to the number of values that appear in the data.

If you want to use treat numeric values as nominal, I believe that you will want to look at the [`Discretize`](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/Discretize.html) filter instead of using the `NumericToNominal` filter.

Comment: The Discretize filter is only appropriate if you want to change the continuous, numeric values into bins (supervised or unsupervised). NumericToNominal is for converting numeric values that represent categorical values but got interpreted by Weka as continuous values (Weka can't tell from a CSV whether a numeric column is in fact numeric or categorical).

Comment: Where it makes sense, you can use the [StringToNominal](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/StringToNominal.html) filter for converting String attributes into Nominal ones.